# Getting Axios Netwrok Error using phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, reactjs, axios

I'm practicing trying to insert data into a phpmyadmin mysql database using React.
I'm using Axios for posting.
When i try to post data from my formto the database table i get axios network. Tried searching the net for solution but cannot seem to understand where i'm gone wrong.
This is my coding; any guidance will be appreciated on where what needs to be amended:

```
    import { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import {useNavigate} from "react-router-dom";
const cors = require('cors');


function AddStudent(){

   // app.use(cors());

    let history = useNavigate();
    const [student, setStudent] = useState({
        first_name:"",
        last_name:"",
        email:""
    })
    const {first_name, last_name, email} = student;

    const handleChange = (e)=>{
setStudent({...student,[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
    }

    const submitForm = async (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();

        console.log(student)

        await axios.post("http://localhost/renting_website/insert.php", student)
        .then((result) =>{
console.log(result);
if(result.data.status === 'valid'){
    history('/ListStudent')
}
else{
    alert('There is a problem in adding; please check everything')
}
        })
    }
    return(
        <form onSubmit = {e => submitForm(e)}>

        <div className="box_size">
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-12 text-center">
                <h1>Add Student</h1>
            </div>
         </div>

            <div className="row">

            <div className="col-md-6">First Name</div>
            <div className="col-md-6">
                <input type='text' name='first_name' className="form-control" 
                value ={first_name} onChange={e => handleChange(e)}/>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-6">Last Name</div>
            <div className="col-md-6">
                <input type='text' name='last_name' className="form-control" 
                 value ={last_name} onChange={e => handleChange(e)}/>
            </div>
            </div>


<div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-6">Email</div>
            <div className="col-md-6">
                <input type='email' name='email' className="form-control" 
                 value ={email} onChange={e => handleChange(e)}/>
            </div>
</div>

     <div className="row">
     <div className="col-md-12">
                <input type='submit' name='submit' className="btn btn-warning"  value="Add_Student"/>
            </div>
         </div>  

         </div>       
       
 </form>     
    )
}

export default AddStudent;
```

insert.php

```
    <?php>
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000/");

header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: access");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,
Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requsted-With");

include('db-connect.php');

$data = json_decode(file_get_content("php://input"))

$first_name = $data->first_name;
$last_name = $data->last_name;
$email = $data->email;

if($first_name && $last_name && $email){
    $sql = "insert into registration(
        first_name,
        last_name,
        email
        )
    values(
        '$first_name',
        '$last_name',
        '$email'

        )";

        $result = mysqli_connect($con, $sql);
    
        if($result){
            'status' =>'valid'
        );
        echo json_encode($reponse)
        }
        else{
            $reponse=array(
                'status' => 'invalid'
            );
            echo json_encode($reponse)
        }
}
<?>
```

and the connection.php:

```
    <?php

$serverName = "localhost";
$userName = "root";
$password = "";
$dbName = "renting";

$con = mysqli_connect($serverName, $userName, $password, $dbName);

?>
```

[image]

Comment: FYI: There is no such thing as "a phpmyadmin my sql database". phpMyAdmin is a frontend / UI, to perform administrative tasks _on_ a MySQL database. It really hasn't anything to do with your error here in particular. (Tag removed.)

Comment: Check what response the request got using your browser dev tools network panel. And if the status code indicates any error, check your PHP error log for more details.

Comment: That's one of the errors i'm getting: add-student:1  Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/renting_website/insert.php' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Not sure why the header is not seen; but your code doesn't look like it was set up to handle a preflight request correctly to begin with. And with the adding of those headers, you are all over the place - you are adding the same header multiple times, which will make PHP _overwrite_ the one you tried to send previously.

Comment: So this is a CORS issue, it's nothing to do with your database - the code never gets that far.  Probably OPTIONS preflight requests are being handled by your webserver directly rather than by php, and isn't returning the necessary headers to allow the browser to permit the CORS request